# Monitoring ROR server (thin or mongrel) for resources and availability in WINDOWS and re-spawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crash, monitoring, application-restart

First thing I would like to say is, i know deploying ror applications in windows is not recommended, but in this case i have no choice due to some client restrictions.

I am looking for a tool like [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)  for windows which will moniter my instance of Thin or Mongrel and will 're-spawn' in case of crashes or availability.

Now I looked around quite a bit and most solutions like UpStart, or Passenger server are only available for Unix environments.

Any known tools for windows? and how to use them?

I am also open to any alternative ror servers for windows that can do this automatically like passenger does.

Thanks
Shaunak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a bat script as a scheduled task to run wmic process, scan to find Mongrel, and if it's not found to run it?

Sorry, I'd do it in bash, or I'd have a code example for you.

This would also make a good python script, in my opinion.